# How to list out directories in a csv file

Tags: python, list, csv, codeigniter, data-science

I am trying to list out directory name and files names and mp4 files and empty directories in a csv. I am getting output but it's printing so many times. any help ? Thanks in advance.

```
import csv
import os
import sys

with open('Files.csv', 'w', newline='') as f:
fieldnames = ['Foldername', 'Filename','mp4filelist','Empty folders']
writer = csv.DictWriter(f, fieldnames=fieldnames)
writer.writeheader()

for dirpath, dirnames, files in os.walk(sys.argv[1]):
    for file_name in files:
        for root, dirs, files in os.walk(sys.argv[1]):
            for file in files:
                if(file.endswith(".mp4")):
    
                    listmp4 = (os.path.join(root,file))
  
                    listOfEmptyDirs = [dirpath for (dirpath, dirnames, filenames) in os.walk(sys.argv[1]) if len(dirnames) == 0 and len(filenames) == 0]
                   for elem in listOfEmptyDirs:

                       writer.writerow({'Foldername' : f'{dirpath}', 'Filename' : file_name, 'mp4filelist' : listmp4, 'Empty folders' : listOfEmptyDirs })
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code you are iteration through the directory twice thats the reason you are having multiple entries

FYI `os.walk(sys.argv[1])` parses the directory recursively so you dont need to call it again

What i get from your requirement is that you need mp4 filename and dirpath, and one column for list of mp4 files and another for list of empty directory so you can do this:

```
import csv
import os
import ctype


def has_hidden_attribute(filepath):
    try:
        attrs = ctypes.windll.kernel32.GetFileAttributesW(unicode(filepath))
        assert attrs != -1
        result = bool(attrs & 2)
    except (AttributeError, AssertionError):
        result = False
    return result

with open('Files.csv', 'w') as f:
    fieldnames = ['Foldername', 'Filename', 'mp4filelist', 'Empty folders']
    writer = csv.DictWriter(f, fieldnames=fieldnames)
    writer.writeheader()
    listOfEmptyDirs = []
    for dirpath, dirnames, files in os.walk(sys.argv[1]):
        print(dirpath, dirnames, files)
        listmp4 = [os.path.join(dirpath, file) for file in files if file.endswith(".mp4")]
        if len(dirnames) == 0 and len(files) == 0 and has_hidden_attribute(dirpath):
            listOfEmptyDirs.append(dirpath)
        for filename in files:
            writer.writerow({'Foldername': str(dirpath), 'Filename': filename, 'mp4filelist': listmp4,
                             'Empty folders': listOfEmptyDirs})
```

Comment: Thank you!!!  But issue with the empty directories , it's not  giving empty directories correctly.

Comment: So if a folder doest have neither have any file nor any folder then its empt folder right so we are checking that and appending it to the list,
Do you want an aggregated list of all empty dirs?

Comment: Yes. Please help me in that. Thanks in advance

Comment: I have edited the answer, mainly i have moved listOfEmptyDirs = [] out of for loop, so that  it aggregates list of all empty dirs.

Comment: Sorry for troubling you @Nishant Patel,  am not getting empty dirs correctly. and I haven't gotten the updated code

Comment: Let's say  I have  5 folders in given path  1,3 folders having files where 2 as empty so it's showing 2 as empty directory that is good but my issue is 4,5 folders are also empty where it's not showing.

Comment: I have updated the code in answer above, So if i am getting you correctly, does 4,5 folder have any empty folder inside it?

Comment: 4,5 folders are empty. Have no files and folders inside it.

Comment: Can you send me a sample output of print(dirpath, dirnames, files) for folder 4 and 5

Comment: Yeah this the output
C:\Softwares\FIle code\New folder (4)  [] []
C:\Softwares\FIle code\New folder (5)  [] []

Comment: Then it must there must be some hidden files and older inside it. I have updated the code to handle that.

Comment: It's showing module error even I installed required module

Comment: ctype module not found

Comment: Do `pip install ctype` and make sure you import ctype